# How to use reference to python int from rust method with pyo3?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

How does one unpack a python integer as a reference from a `rust` class method?

I'm trying to expose a rust struct to python but the interpreter complains about the reference to the `i32`.

This is the code:

```rust
#[pyclass]
pub struct DataMap {
    entries: HashMap<i32, DataEntry>,
}
#[pymethods]
impl DataMap {
    #[new]
    fn new() -> DataMap {
        DataMap {
            entries: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
    fn insert(&mut self, key: i32, x: i32, y: i32) {
        let entry = DataEntry::new(x, y);
        self.entries.insert(key, entry);
    }
    fn get_entry(&self, key: &i32) -> Option<DataEntry> {
        if self.entries.contains_key(key) {
            Some(self.entries[key])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```bash
  --> src/data_structure.rs:46:30
   |
46 |     fn get_entry(&self, key: &i32) -> Option<DataEntry> {
   |                              ^ the trait `PyClass` is not implemented for `&i32`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `PyClass`:
             DataEntry
             DataMap
   = note: required for `&i32` to implement `FromPyObject<'_>`
   = note: required for `&i32` to implement `PyFunctionArgument<'_, '_>`
note: required by a bound in `extract_argument`
  --> /Users/gareth/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pyo3-0.18.3/src/impl_/extract_argument.rs:86:8
   |
86 |     T: PyFunctionArgument<'a, 'py>,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `extract_argument`
```

It seems to be asking to implement the PyClass trait for `i32`, but I'm not sure how to do this in this context. My confusion stems from how references are handled between Python and Rust and how `pyo3` should be used to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

> My confusion stems from how references are handled between Python and Rust and how pyo3 should be used to implement this.

It's should not be, ask for an `i32`.

There is [*very little* support for getting references out of python objects](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/conversion/trait.FromPyObject.html#impl-FromPyObject%3C%27source%3E-for-Cow%3C%27source,+%5Bu8%5D%3E), because the layouts don't match, so getting a Rust object out of a Python one usually requires copying and reformatting the data. The only exceptions which ship with pyo3 are `&str` and `&[u8]` (and `Cow<'a, [u8]>`).

Plus that tends to be of limited use as it would preclude dropping the GIL, which is often what you want. Not to mention an `&i32` just takes more resources than an `i32`, it's completely pointless.

Comment: When trying to do the same code but with an i32 I get a compilation error to the effect of "expected `&i32`, found `i32`" - do you have suggestions for what approach would work?

Comment: @songololo Just take a reference: `&key`.